# Install custom notification sound with app

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I want to ship a custom mp3 notification sound with my app. I also want the user to be able to change the notification sound to a different one and also the change it back to the one shipped using the standard android notification sound picker UI.  My strategy is to copy mysound.mp3 to a folder named “Notifications”.  When I do this manually my phone automatically finds the notification so that it can be picked through the UI.  I have been able to programmatically copy the mysound.mp3 file from res/raw to another folder but I can’t copy it to the folder I want it to go to. In some cases I can copy the file to a directory named Notifications under my apps files but the notification sound picker UI doesn’t see it there.

I am new to Android and I don’t even know if apps are allowed to copy to a Notifications folder. I am open to a different strategy. Here is my code.

```
    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mysound);
    String destDir;

    //Options for destination directory I tried but that didn't work
    destDir = "";
    destDir = "/data";
    destDir = this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_NOTIFICATIONS).toString();
    destDir = this.getCacheDir().toString();
    destDir = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    destDir = this.getExternalCacheDir().toString();

    File myDir = new File(destDir + "/Notifications");
    myDir.mkdirs();

    File destinationFile = new File(myDir + "/dundun.mp3");
    destinationFile.delete(); //TODO: Delete this line when copy is working
    Boolean exists = destinationFile.exists();
    if (exists) return;

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out =  new FileOutputStream(destinationFile.toString());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read = 0;

    try
    {
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: I think you have to trigger the MediaScanner to add the file to the sound database after you copy it. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener)

Comment: Thanks Karakuri. I am exploring that path now. I am getting a uri back from onScanCompleted() which I will need but the sound still isn't showing up in the notification picker UI.

Comment: Are you still copying it to the notifications directory?

Comment: I gave up on using MediaScanner and decided to try using MediaStore. That wasn't working either. Afterwards I added permissions to the manifest file and got the sound to show up in the Notification picker, however, it doesn't make a noise when selected. I may go back and try media scanner again now that I have the right permissions in the manifest.

Comment: @HappyPawn8: Any solution to this?