# How to let the user revert to an app-custom sound?

Tags: android, audio, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

An Android O app can set a custom sound on a NotificationChannel using an app sound resource:

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.customSound);
AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
    .build();
channel.setSound(uri, audioAttributes);
```

Now in the system settings, the user can reconfigure the NotificationChannel, picking a different sound from the system's sound resources.

**Problem:** That list of sounds does not include the app's own sound resources, so the user can never revert to the app's custom sound resource after changing it.

**Q.** How can the app let the user restore the app's custom sound resource? Does the app have to [copy the sound file to a shared directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31282465) (and make that work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channels are one-shoot, after the creation the app can't modify them. So you could delete the channel and create it again or you can copy your sound resource file in the public directory to let the user select it when he adjusts the channel settings.

Comment: To get the custom sound into the pick list, "copy to the public directory" is viable. Where's info on making that work? Which directory? Access permissions? What if it gets deleted? How to tell if a new release needs to replace it? How to clean it up on app uninstall? Is there an easier approach?

Comment: You just need to copy a file in Alarms or Notifications or other folder. Same procedure to use a custom sound as ringer for example. You need the write external storage permission.

Comment: OK. It'd be so much better if there was a way to include the app's sound resources in the pick list.

Comment: According to [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-o-how-to-use-notification-channels--cms-28616), "deleted channels remain visible in the notification settings so as to prevent spam." So the app can't work around user control by deleting and recreating a channel.

Comment: I have tested the delete and recreation trick but all the non-modifiable attributes (sound, light, vibration, etc) will **get restored** from the deleted one. The only thing you can change is its name. so there's basically no way to change them with the **same** channel id. The fact that the app is restricted from this access in Oreo and newer versions of Android is a bummer.

Comment: Could someone post a solution for copying the custom sound into Notifications folder so that the custom sound shows up for the user?